# How to get the path of my include files in vb.net 2005?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a folder inside my project and i put an icon on it, now i want to use it as my program icon how will i get the link of my icon inside misc folder?

[image: include file vb.net]

Answer (score 1):

1. Double-click "My Project".
2. Open the "Application" tab.
3. Change "Icon" to "<Browse...>"
4. Navigate to your icon and select it.  Press "Open".

Comment: Although this answer is correct, you *should* create application icons in the Resources section of your application (`My Project>Resources Tab>Icons Dropdown`) then you can use this icon without having to browse in `My Project>Application>Icon` (it will show up as `Resources\IconName.ico`)

Answer (score 0):

The actual path will be `"..\..\Misc\app.ico"`. But that will not be available when you deploy your application. Your best bet is add it under your project settings so that it will be added as a resource in your application. If you want to do it manualy you will need to make sure the app.ico file is in your application directory and your path adjusted accordingly `"app.ico"` or if you have an images directory `".\Images\app.ico"`